# Unable to click on datepicker element which of type input text

Tags: java, selenium, datepicker

I am trying to use Selenium to automate a webpage which has a calendar icon which upon clicking pops up a calendar frame.

Screenshots:
[image: here] 
[image: here]

I'm unable to bring up that datepicker frame by clicking on the calendar icon  which is an input HTML element with type text. How do I handle this in Selenium?

Comment: Can you please share `HTML` code?

Comment: If your goal is to _automate_ the given page, not to test the UI, then I suggest trying to use `sendKeys()` on the input. Manually inspect the UI to see what value gets passed into the `input` tag, and use `sendKeys()` on the input element, using the same DateTime format. Depending on what `datePickerClick()` does, this may not work, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about you HTML element but I solve my problem use the following XPath

```
//table[@class='Your class']//div[.='28']
```